# Sonata admin tabs in page

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I use Sonata admin Generator.
I'd like to create multiple lists from a symfony class.
For example I have a list of invoices and I would like to create a tab with paid bills, an other tab with pending bills and a last tab with invoices disabled.
This status is in the class.
I saw [this page](http://demo.sonata-project.org/admin/sonata/media/gallery/list?context=sonata_product)(admin/admin) in the Sonata demo who use context but I wouldn't like install mediabundle if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible without the mediabundle. 
I had the same use-case as you with 'project-statuses'. These statuses are in my database.

A few steps are necessary:

1. Override the CRUDController. Maybe this step isn't needed, but I couldn't figure out how to without. I want to display the different statuses as tabs, so I inject a collection in the list-template.

Make your own CRUDController:

```
    namespace Your\OwnBundle\Controller;

    use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as Controller;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    class ProjectCrudController extends Controller
    {
        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         *
         * @param Request $request
         */
        public function render($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null, Request $request = null)
        {
            $projectStatusRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('EvinceObjectsBundle:ProjectStatus');
            // here inject the params you'll need
            // you can do it only when $parameters['action'] == 'list' if you want
            $parameters['projectStatuses'] = $projectStatusRepo->findAll();
            $parameters['activeProjectStatus'] = $request->get('status', 1);

            return parent::render($view, $parameters, $response);
        }
    }
```

Inject your own CRUDController in the services.yml (or xml)

```
    sonata.admin.project:
        class: Your\OwnBundle\Admin\ProjectAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "project", label: "Project" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Your\OwnBundle\Entity\Project
            - YourOwnBundle:ProjectCrud
        calls:
            - [ setLabelTranslatorStrategy, ["@sonata.admin.label.strategy.underscore"]]
            - [ setTemplate, [list, YourOwnBundle:ProjectAdmin:list.html.twig]]
```

Notice the setTemplate-call, so lets create your template

2. Create your own list-template

   ```
   {% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list.html.twig' %}

   {% block preview %}

       <ul class="nav nav-pills">
           <li><a><strong>{{ "label.select_projectstatus"|trans({}, 'SonataProjectBundle') }}</strong></a></li>

           {% for projectStatus in projectStatuses %}
               {% set active = false %}
               {% if projectStatus.id == activeProjectStatus %}
                   {% set active = true %}
               {% endif %}
               <li class="{% if active %}active{% endif %}" ><a href="{{ admin.generateUrl('list', {'status' : projectStatus.id }) }}">{{ projectStatus.status }}</a></li>
           {% endfor %}
       </ul>
   {% endblock %}
   ```
3. Override the Admin::getFilterParameters function in your own admin class. Here you want to set the filter based on your requestparam:

   ```
   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public function getFilterParameters()
   {
       $parameters = parent::getFilterParameters();   

       return array_merge(array(
           'status'  => array(
               'type' => '',
               'value' => $this->getRequest()->get('status', 1),
           )
       ), $parameters);
   }
   ```